# Hugo Website giving XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document error while using custom sitemap

Tags: xml, sitemap, netlify, hugo

I was trying to add a custom sitemap for my Hugo blog website. I went to [hugo sitemap guide](https://gohugo.io/templates/sitemap-template/), there it was mentioned the sitemap which I am using.

```
{{ printf "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" standalone=\"yes\" ?>" | safeHTML }}
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
  xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  {{ range .Data.Pages }}
  <url>
    <loc>{{ .Permalink }}</loc>{{ if not .Lastmod.IsZero }}
    <lastmod>{{ safeHTML ( .Lastmod.Format "2006-01-02T15:04:05-07:00" ) }}</lastmod>{{ end }}{{ with .Sitemap.ChangeFreq }}
    <changefreq>{{ . }}</changefreq>{{ end }}{{ if ge .Sitemap.Priority 0.0 }}
    <priority>{{ .Sitemap.Priority }}</priority>{{ end }}{{ if .IsTranslated }}{{ range .Translations }}
    <xhtml:link
                rel="alternate"
                hreflang="{{ .Lang }}"
                href="{{ .Permalink }}"
                />{{ end }}
    <xhtml:link
                rel="alternate"
                hreflang="{{ .Lang }}"
                href="{{ .Permalink }}"
                />{{ end }}
  </url>
  {{ end }}
</urlset>
```

Getting this Error when I push to netlify
I have checked the white space, but it doesn't look like there is any white space, any help will be appreciated.

```
error on line 2 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
```

[My website](https://blog.blurcode.in/sitemap.xml)

Comment: If you look at the source of your page, you can see the XML declaration is printed twice. I assume you either mistakenly entered it twice, or there is a bug in the safeHTML function. Either way, you can just remove it since a declaration is not mandatory in XML.

Comment: Thanks for the fix, I am also facing one more issue https://blurcode.in/sitemap.xml If you check my sitemap, there is no domain name before URL, which is causing google webmaster to reject the sitemap